# How to run two animations side by side in Maple

Tags: animation, maple

I am trying to run two animations simultaneously side by side. If I place both the animations in an array they display properly but they won't run together. If I display them together so that they run in unison then they are superimposed instead of side by side. Is there a standard way for Maple to do this the way I need?

Answer (score 0):

[edited] It's unclear to me whether you want something that can be right-click exported to a single animated GIF file that contains both animations.[/edited]

You can construct a single animation where each frame is itself a side-by-side array-plot.

Here are two ways to construct an animation of an array-plot. Of course, for your own example you would replace the calls `plot(sin(...))` and `plot(cos(...))` with whatever commands constructed your two plots that depend on the animating parameter `t`.

```
restart; 
T:=4: 
step:=10: 
numframes:=100:
```

1) Use the `plots:-animate` command, and delay the evaluation of the extra arguments (until `t` gets numeric values).

```
plots:-animate(plots:-display, 
               ['Array([plot(sin(x+t),x=0..1), 
                        plot(cos(x+t),x=0..1)])'], 
               t=0..T*step, frames=numframes);
```

2) Generate a sequence of them, and then use the `plots:-display` command with its `insequence` option

```
S := [seq(plots:-display(Array([plot(sin(x+t),x=0..1), 
                                plot(cos(x+t),x=0..1)])), 
          t=0..T*step, (T*step-0)/(numframes-1))]: 

nops(S); # check we got 100 frames 

plots:-display(S, insequence=true);
```

Using either of those two methods then, upon clicking for focus in the plot area, the play button in the main menubar causes the Arrays of plots to play together.

Comment: The above requires the same number of frames for both plots. I could add that an alternative would be to insert two PlotComponents and a Button whose action code would make two calls to make both of them play. If lucky there would be no noticeable delay between when both started playing, upon pressing the Button. Insert all these from the Components palette is separate manual effort, though. If you really want you can even programmatically insert/embed all three Components (using the two pre-made animations as functional arguments) but it's more programming. Let me know.